# store and output formatted array contents with sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Environment: Ruby 1.9.2

I am new to Ruby/Sinatra and am creating a proof of concept web application. The purpose is fairly simple: A user inputs a list of domains and the script first checks their mx records, and if they meet the condition, pulls out the domain contact information. I am fairly sure that I am not going about storing the data appropriately and am looking for a more elegant solution that will enable me to style the results such that domain, email, and name are grouped together.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "sinatra/base"
require 'rubygems'
require 'haml'
require 'sinatra'
require 'whois'

get '/' do
  haml :index
end

post '/' do
  @host = params[:host]
  @host.split('\n')
  @email = Array.new
  @name = Array.new
  @domain = Array.new
  @host.each_line {|i|
      if %x[dig -t mx #{i.chomp.gsub('www.', '')} | grep -i mx | grep -i google].empty?
        puts "empty"
      else
        @domain << i.chomp.gsub('www.','')
        @email << (Whois.whois(i.chomp.gsub('www.',''))).technical_contact.email
        @name << (Whois.whois(i.chomp.gsub('www.',''))).technical_contact.name
      end
}

  haml :index
end

__END__
@@ layout
%html
  %head
    %title Gcrawl
  %body
    #header
      %h1 Gcrawl
    #content
      =yield
  %footer

@@ index
%p
  Welcome to Gcrawl

%form(action='/' method='POST')
  %textarea{:rows => '12', :cols => '40', :name => 'host'}
  %input(type='submit')
- if defined?(@email)
  %h3= @domain
  %h3= @email
  %h3= @name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class `Record` which will contain @name, @domain and @email for a particular entry.
So, each instance of `Record` will have it's own name, domain and email.

Replace the array implementation with a Class. If you need to store the records in a database, use `ActiveRecord`.

It's good that you started with Sinatra, but if you are in a hurry, you can get your app running on Rails in an hour.

**EDIT**
Tutorials/Guides for getting started with Rails:

- [Rails Guides - Getting Started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)
- [rubyonrailstutorials.com](http://www.rubyonrailstutorials.com/)
- [railstutor.com](http://railstutor.com/)